# IOS8 Objective-C SignaturePoint CGRectValue

Tags: objective-c

Below is the output for "signature.rawPoints" with 32bit architecture Objective-C code

```
(
        "NSRect: {{130, 142.5}, {2.3333333, 100}}",
        "NSRect: {{136, 139.5}, {2.4990008, 101}}",
        "NSRect: {{152.25, 131}, {2.0691545, 102}}",
        "NSRect: {{169.75, 121}, {1.7328094, 103}}",
        "NSRect: {{185.25, 111}, {1.5653242, 104}}",
        "NSRect: {{196.125, 104}, {1.6099705, 105}}",
        "NSRect: {{200.75, 101.375}, {1.9532523, 106}}"
    ),
```

But with 64bit architecture along with IOS8 below is the output

```
(
        "\nlocation: 87.000000,112.000000\nvelocity: 0.000000,0.000000\nacceleration: 0.000000,0.000000\ntimestamp: 19476.794956\npressure: 1.000000\ndiameter: 4.666667\nid: 100",
        "\nlocation: 88.000000,116.000000\nvelocity: 22.341108,89.364433\nacceleration: 499.125115,1996.500461\ntimestamp: 19476.839717\npressure: 1.000000\ndiameter: 5.006714\nid: 101",
        "\nlocation: 92.000000,125.000000\nvelocity: 228.450167,514.012876\nacceleration: 11771.412252,24252.751985\ntimestamp: 19476.857226\npressure: 1.000000\ndiameter: 4.700317\nid: 102",
        "\nlocation: 97.000000,134.000000\nvelocity: 298.178096,536.720573\nacceleration: 4158.268213,1354.187550\ntimestamp: 19476.873995\npressure: 1.000000\ndiameter: 4.437694\nid: 103")
```

The below code is not working with 64-bit architecture on the above rawpoints to find CGRectValues.

```
CGRect r1 = [[[signature.rawPoints objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j] CGRectValue];
```

Error:

> 2015-06-04 19:18:45.933 MySampleCloset UAT[40174:865394]
>   -[T1SignaturePoint CGRectValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f90d86b75a0 2015-06-04 19:18:45.977 MySampleCloset
>   UAT[40174:865394] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[T1SignaturePoint
>   CGRectValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f90d86b75a0'

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code carefully. Unrecognized selector means, that you try to use method to "wrong" object, like treating `NSString` as an `NSArray` for example, and sending `NSString` `objectAtIndex` message.

Or maybe, you using some kind of 3rd libraries, and they are not updated for 64 bit architecture.

If you want better answer then that, edit your code with `CMD+K` and show us your code..

Comment: for (int j=0; j<[[signature.rawPoints objectAtIndex:i]count]-1; j++) {    
    CGRect r1 = [[[signature.rawPoints objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j] CGRectValue];
   CGRect r2 = [[[signature.rawPoints objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j + 1] CGRectValue];
    CGPoint p1 = r1.origin;
    CGPoint p2 = r2.origin;  
     totalPoints = totalPoints + [self distanceBetweenPoint:p1 andPoint:p2];
    } 
     if ((hasRetina && totalPoints>kFingerSignatureThreshold) || (!hasRetina && totalPoints>kFingerSignatureThreshold)) {
            break;
      }}

Comment: Pls find the above code and the error mesg that we are getting with IOS8.2 and 64bit compiler. Basically the "signature.rawPoints" output layouts itself diff with IOS8.2 and less than 8version, the outpus which I mentioned above in the 1st query. Pls let me know the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

TSignaturePoint.h added into the latest third point TSignature library, so we have to use the below code to find the x and y co ordinates for the signature of every letter.

CGPoint p = [[[signature.rawPoints objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j] location];

Note: [[signature.rawPoints objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j] is the type of TSignature.

we can also write the above as below
TSignature * sig = [[signature.rawPoints objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:j];
CGPoint p = sig.location;